# Use hmset / hmget in REDIS: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis

I am trying to use hmset / hmget to store hashmaps associated to a key in REDIS as such:

```
def self.store_id_and_phone(id, phone)
  key = generate_key
  REDIS.hmset(key, :id, id, :phone, phone)
  REDIS.expire(key, 15.minutes)
  verification_code_url_key
end

def self.generate_key
  return ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(5)
end

def self.get_id_and_phone(key)
  return REDIS.hmget(key, :id, :phone)
end
```

However I sometimes get this error at `REDIS.hmget`

> WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

It doesn't happen all the time tho, **about 3% of all the requests**.

Did anyone encounter similar issues before? Please shed some light. Thanks!

Comment: Does your code writes keys elsewhere? This error is thrown because your key does not store a Hash but a different data type. You could perhaps try catching this and printing the response from `REDIS.type(key)` to help you trace the type of value.

Comment: Thanks @ItamarHaber! There are other places that write keys, but given that I used SecureRandom to generate the key, I guess the conflict rate shouldn't be as high as 3%? I added the code that generates REDIS key. Maybe increase from 5 to a higher number would improve?